# Pyqtgraph. Draw text label next to the rectangle

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to draw a grid of rectangles with text labels on each rectangle. I am using this code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
vb = win.addViewBox(col=0, row=0)

board = ['1234',
         'abcd',
         'efgh']

def draw_board(board):
    for j, row in enumerate(board):
        for i, cell in enumerate(row):
            r = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(i, -j, 0.9, 0.9)
            r.setPen(pg.mkPen((0, 0, 0, 100)))
            r.setBrush(pg.mkBrush((50, 50, 200)))
            vb.addItem(r)

            t = pg.TextItem(cell, (255, 255, 255), anchor=(i, -j))
            vb.addItem(t)

    pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()

draw_board(board)
```

For some reason labels seem to be drawn in a completely different coordinate system that even uses different scale. What is the easy way to put my labels in the middle of the respective rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with this code:

```
t_up = pg.TextItem(cell, (255, 255, 255), anchor=(0, 0))
t_up.setPos(i + 0.5, -j + 0.5)
```